# Is there a way to release OfflineAudioContext memory allocation?

Tags: javascript, html, machine-learning, electron, web-audio-api

Now I'm developing a software from Electron. It is a music player application.

What I would to do is I have to extract audio feature from (an) incoming song(s). This is not realtime extraction because I would like to extract feature entire of a song.

I use a library call [Meyda](https://github.com/meyda/meyda) and Web Audio API. I have noticed that my implementation consume amount of RAM (about ~2,000 MB).

Here is my implementation:

```
let offlineCtx = new OfflineAudioContext(
  2,
  duration * sampleRate,
  sampleRate
)
let source = offlineCtx.createBufferSource()

let buffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(songData.buffer)
source.buffer = buffer
source.connect(offlineCtx.destination)
source.start()

const SLICING_WINDOW_SIZE = 1024
let renderedBuffer = await offlineCtx.startRendering()
let channelData = await renderedBuffer.getChannelData(0)
let results = []
for (let i = 0; i < channelData.length - SLICING_WINDOW_SIZE; i += SLICING_WINDOW_SIZE) {
  const r = Meyda.extract(
    'mfcc',
    channelData.slice(i, i + SLICING_WINDOW_SIZE)
  )
  results.push(r)
}
```

Is there a way to reduce RAM consuming? Thanks!